# Cross-site Scripting (XSS) using a hyphen

Tags: javascript, xss

If I type this into Chrome's console I get the alert showing:

```
'some string'-alert(1)-'another string'
```

If I instead type following in I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`:

```
'some string'alert(1)'another string'
```

What is the significance in the hyphens enabling the alert to be executed?

Comment: Evaluated as minus not hyphen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First one is evaluated as:  *String .. minus .. result of function call .. minus .. String*.

Using subtraction with strings casts them to number or `NaN`

The alert fires simply because it is a function. It's return value is undefined.

So after alert fires you effectively have `NaN - undefined - NaN` which returns `NaN` which is what you see in console

Answer (score 3):

Because Javascript isn't strongly typed, you can (attempt) to subtract strings. Because of this, the interpreter is evaluating each part of the expression, one of which is the `alert`. This causes a popup to appear. The interpreter/compiler cannot compile the second one due to incorrect syntax.